Are Windows ReFS file-level snapshots what File History should have been?
The first impression I had when coming across Windows File History was that multiple versions of a file would be saved every time said file was changed, and that those versions would be listed in the Previous Versions tab of the file's Properties dialog.
But Windows File History is basically just a glorified scheduled backup of files in selected folders and snapshots/versions aren't saved when a file changes, so if I edit a file 10 times in an hour, there won't be 10 versions of the file, just the single version that reflects the final edited file before the scheduled File History backup executes.
I've read about Windows ResilientFS (ReFS) and it supports file-level snapshots. Is this a proper file history/versioning?

Snapshotting at every change would cause problems with many applications that continuously modify a file. It seems like adjusting the snapshot interval to suit you is a better solution. I'm not sure about NTFS, but on other filesystems taking a snapshot every 5 minutes is perfectly fine.

Not Really
The closer analogy is the Volume Shadow Copy service (VSS) used to implement restore points and provide a consistent point-in-time view of the filesystem for backups.
The difference here is that the VSS operates at the block level (equivalently to the snapshot functionality in LVM on Linux, or to taking a snapshot of a virtual hard disk for a VM), while the snapshot functionality in ReFS operates within the filesystem itself (equivalently to how snapshots work on ZFS, BTRFS, or APFS). If you want a full explanation on how all this works, see the very end of the answer.
This is really important for a couple of reasons:

It can be far more efficient than a block-level copy, because the ‘changes’ that get stored are much more specific to what actually changed.
It can be far faster than a block-level copy, because if implemented correctly it ends up being just a bit of metadata manipulation in the filesystem.
It can be selective. This is really the important bit. A volume shadow copy can technically choose to only snapshot some things, but the way that is handled gets really really complicated. In comparison, for properly implemented snapshots in the filesystem itself, it’s free.

But it could be a core part of an implementation of such a feature.
Most operating systems, including Windows, have some way to intercept certain filesystem operations and do things in response to them. Using that, it is in fact possible to do basic file versioning with filesystem snapshots by simply intercepting writes (and a handful of other operations) and taking a snapshot of the file before the write actually completes.
Nobody actually does this though for a couple of reasons:

Outside of the Windows world, the norm for ‘updating’ most types of files that users would actually want to track versions for involves writing the updated data out to a temporary file and then replacing the existing one. This is really important for ensuring that the update either happens or doesn’t, because essentially everywhere (including on Windows) a file rename is an atomic operation (it either happens or it doesn’t, there’s no intermediate state that could occur). This, however, is complicated to handle outside of the filesystem itself if you want to ensure you get a snapshot of the file about to be replaced, and also hurts the efficiency of storing the snapshot.
On Windows specifically, the VFS layer already has some pretty serious efficiency problems, and this would add yet more performance issues to it.
Most people who really need versioning for files are already using either versioning functionality that is provided by the file format itself (this is very common in many document formats) or a proper version control system. This is partly because of no solution like this existing, but it’s also partly because most cases where you need file versioning require more than just storing old versions.

Those factors are significant enough that there is limited demand for such functionality, and thus nobody has really gone about making it.

You may be interested to know that there actually do exist filesystems that have full file versioning. The two most widely used examples are probably Files-11 from OpenVMS, and Fossil from Plan 9 (not to be confused with the Fossil VCS/SCM software). Files-11 actually worked very similarly to how you initially thought File History worked, just inside the filesystem itself. Fossil worked much more like a version control system under the hood, but presented a similar interface. Such filesystems are not widely used anymore though, because that type of versioning was not usually considered a worthwhile feature in a filesystem.
For ReFS, ZFS, BTRFS, and APFS though, things work differently. At their core, all four filesystems use Copy-on-Write (CoW) semantics to perform at least part of the updates to the file metadata and data. The general premise is pretty simple, whenever you go to update something you create a copy, update the copy, and then update the thing pointing at that data to point at the copy. The key point here are that because you copy something whenever you update it, it’s safe to have multiple references to it, but any references that weren’t updated keep pointing at the old version. In a filesystem, those references are known as ‘reflinks’, and they are a core part of both filesystem-level deduplication, and filesystem-level snapshots.
Since creating a new reflink is just a simple metadata operation, it’s very cheap to create a virtual ‘copy’ of a file, you just update metadata in the right place. That’s all that a snapshot is if it’s a single file, and the ‘old version’ sticking around is free (other than storage space, but that’s not super expensive because this is operating in terms of filesystem blocks, not whole files). And because a (normal) CoW filesystem also uses CoW semantics for it’s metadata updates, you can snapshot an entire directory tree just as quickly and efficiently by simply creating a new reflink to the directory itself (and because metadata is copy-on-write as well, that’s all you need to do).

Thanks for such a detailed and expansive answer, I remember the file versioning in VMS during my student days using VAX 11/780 and later, it worked very well but IIRC the previous versions of a file where visible in the directory, which wasn't too bad but would be a nightmare in modern GUI file managers.  The "purge" command in VMS got a lot of use for cleaning up previous file versions.

"it’s also partly because most cases where you need file versioning require more than just storing old versions" – Exactly. The value of a VCS is in its metadata, specifically, the commit message telling you why something was changed. File versioning only gives you the who, the what, and the when. Some VCSs in additional allow you to distinguish between the author (the person who actually wrote the content within the change) and the committer (the person who performs the physical task of updating the file). File versioning cannot make that distinction.

You are comparing apples and oranges.  File History was born due to the fact that the vast majority of Windows desktop users - specifically home users - were not making backups of their data.  Interestingly, this was discovered from MS's telemetry, but thats not part of this discussion.  "Traditional" backup software that has been used for decades with normal, full, incremental, daily backups was confusing to these users.  So Microsoft created the File History feature.  Is it a robust backup solution?  Absolutely not.  However, it was simple to set up and use.
ReFS is a file system.  It does have the ability to keep and restore file changes and is likely the future of Windows file system.  While it is a resilient file system, it is not a backup solution like File History (better than nothing).  Even with ReFS, you should still be making proper backups.

True, file versioning is certainly not an alternative to traditional backups which I do anyway, but my expectation of File History was that it would maintain versions of files, which it does, but just not in real time, which I'm guessing ReFS would do.  I'm guessing ReFS file versioning would rely on a separate disk for file versioning?

@endurium - OneDrive handles file versions much better. I speak specifically about (Excel, Word, PowerPoint, etc.) not binary files. File History nor OneDrive would really handle blobs of binary data.
